# Different amount values for different select option using PayPal

Tags: php

I am trying to have different amount values in each option when user selects an option.

```
<tr>
    <td><label>Please Select</label><font size="2" color="red">*</font></td>
    <td>
    <select name="Service" id="Service" title="Choose the choice of service!" class="validate[required]">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">1 Session @ $9.90</option>
        <option value="40">40 Sessions @ $428</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php
if($_POST['$Service']==40){
echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='428.00'>";
} else {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='9.90'>";
}
?>
```

So this is what I tried using this logic: If the user were to select an option with value 40, it wil write the amount as 428.00 but if its not 40, then the value is at 9.90

However, when in PayPal it only shows 9.90. The if else statement is not working as its not recognising when someone selects the value 40.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can not use `$` for the index, `$_POST` indexes are accessible through their name

Replace `if($_POST['$Service']==40){` with `if($_POST['Service']==40){`

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
<tr>
<td><label>Please Select</label><font size="2" color="red">*</font></td>
<td>
    <select name="amount" id="amount" title="Choose the choice of service!" class="validate[required]">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="9.90">1 Session @ $9.90</option>
        <option value="428">40 Sessions @ $428</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["amount"])){
        $amount = $_POST["amount"];
    }
    echo $amount;
?>
```